# Understanding Lang's application of two-minus sign products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

This is very basic stuff from the first chapter of Lang's *Basic Mathematics*, but I can't get past it. [Lang here uses a previously established rule to prove that (-1)(-1) = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDUdw.png)

[image: Lang here uses a previously established rule to prove that (-1)(-1) = 1]

but I cannot reason out his steps. How is what he's worked out an application of the rule he cites? What's a and what's b here? I tried doing it on my own and couldn't reason through it.

Comment: Which part is confusing, the second equation or the one at the bottom of the image?

Comment: The application of the rule - where he demonstrates going from (-1)(-1) -> -(1(-1)) = -(-1) = 1. I understand the steps but not how they relate to the rule he mentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! The part that might be a bit confusing is that on each of the $2$ equal signs in the steps he's taking $a$ and $b$ to be different values. I'll try to make it a bit clearer.

---

We have the rule
$$
(-\color{green}{a})\color{blue}{b} =-(\color{green}{a}\color{blue}{b})
$$
So taking $\color{green}{a} =\color{green}{1}$ and $\color{blue}{b} = \color{blue}{-1}$ we get
$$
(-\color{green}{1})(\color{blue}{-1}) =-(\color{green}{1}(\color{blue}{-1})) \tag{1}
$$
Now, we also have the second property
$$
\color{purple}{a}(-\color{darkblue}{b}) = -(\color{purple}{a}\color{darkblue}{b})
$$
So now, taking $\color{purple}{a} = \color{purple}{1}$ and $\color{darkblue}{b} = \color{darkblue}{1}$ we get
$$
\color{purple}{1}(-\color{darkblue}{1}) = -(\color{purple}{1}\cdot\color{darkblue}{1}) = - 1 \tag{2}
$$
since $1\cdot 1 = 1$ by definition of the multiplicative identity. Now notice that the left-hand side of $(2)$ is inside the outermost parenthesis in the right-hand side of $(1)$ so combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$
(-1)(-1) \overset{(1)}{=} -(\color{brown}{1(-1)}) \overset{\color{brown}{(2)}}{=} -(\color{brown}{-1})
$$
Lastly, the author uses the previously proven result $-(-1) = 1$ to get the last equality.

Comment: This clears it up! I thought both a and b were supposed to represent -1, since the first expression was (-1)(-1), and I got stuck reasoning that way because I couldn't get any expressions to match the form of the rule. Should've noticed (1) which makes it much more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The notation is a little slippery, and you may be interested to hear that historically, people squabbled for centuries over the definition of negative numbers and how to multiply them together.

Let's add a useless 0 to the equation, then try to work out what
$$
0+(-1)\times(-1)
$$
is, is it $-1$ or $1$ or $0$ or something else?

Applying the rule once gives us
$$
0+-(1)\times(-1)
$$
which is
$$
0-(1)\times(-1)
$$
by the usual rules for adding negative numbers.

Then applying the rule again gives
$$
0-(-(1\times1))
$$
Now clearly $1\times1=1$ so this is
$$
0-(-1)
$$
and using the rule for subtracting negative numbers gives us
$$
0+1=1
$$
so we have $(-1)\times(-1)=1$.

Comment: Why did you add the zero?

Comment: The point of the zero is to distinguish between the $-$ used for addition and subtraction and the $-$ used for multplication.